# How to change kik bot config?

Tags: kik

It seems like after initial config POST request I can't change any properties (webhook and features), what is the way to change those? is this a temporary bug? :)

```
{
    "webhook": "http://example.com/api/kik",
    "features": {} 
}
```

what I get

```
{
  "webhook": "http://example.com/incoming",
  "features": {
    "receiveReadReceipts": false,
    "receiveIsTyping": false,
    "manuallySendReadReceipts": false,
    "receiveDeliveryReceipts": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The python library has a `set_configuration` function, that if called with a Config object with just a webhook set, will set the webhook. See http://kik.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user.html#configuration, though there’s a bug in those docs right now, the seconds function is `set_configuration`

If you aren't using that library can you show me what code you are using. Blank out your bot-name and api-key